# Error with Embedded code blocks using Javascript in .net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I get an error Unterminated String Constant when I give like this

```
 <input type="button" name="cancel" value="Close" onClick="javascript:top.location.href = '../admin/page.aspx?curTab=<%=curTab%>';">
```

And I get unterminated string Constant and syntax error for this at the '&' for the following line of code

```
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Close" onClick="javascript:top.location.href = 'plan.aspx?res=<%=Request("res")%>&Count=<%=Request("count")%>';">
```

Can anybody please tell me whys this happens?I suppose this is because of the embedded code block. Please help me

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Is this code in the ASPX?

Comment: @MichaelLiu : Yes. Its in aspx.

Comment: Can you post several of the preceding lines too?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this scenario can be handled inline. Try to prepare the text to be rendered inside onclick='[]' beforehand. For your first statement, for example:

```
    <%
    var bb = String.Format("javascript:top.location.href = \"../admin/page.aspx?curTab={0}\";", curTab);
%>
<input type="button" name="cancel" value="Close" onClick='<%=bb%>'>
```

Similarly, you can see standard C# syntax to escape & as well for the second statement.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried according. Now also I get the same error "Unterminated String Constant" . Did it give any error for you?